# Under what circumstances does editing your answer move it up the page?

Tags: support, answers, badges

I answered a still-open question that had two other answers. Being the most recent, mine appeared at the top of the page. I later noticed that one of the other answers had just been edited and was now at the top of the page. I haven't seen that before.

It's not an issue for me; this person gives incredibly thorough and helpful answers (and has a jillionK rep, FWIW.) I just wondered what the conditions are that editing an answer would move it up the page.

(Hmm...this isn't about the editing is it? He or she earned the "move my answer up the page" badge? What's the acronym for slapping palm on forehead?)

Comment: Right. I think "editing" threw off my search. So do I delete this?

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience; tied posts (sorted by "votes") will sort randomly. Accepted answers are always at the top when sorting by "votes". Sorting by *active* will of course show recently edited posts at the top.

It sounds like you may be sorting by "active", which means the edited post will show up first (just verified that this is true even with accepted answers).

There is no "move my answer up the page" badge, in fact, the only badge that *does* anything is the gold tag badge (dupe-hammer). The rest are just shiny.

Comment: There were no upvotes. I had no idea activity moved up answers. That must be it.

Comment: @sjoy It only does if you sort on "active". The default is "votes" you probably changed it on accident.

Comment: Oh, okay...got it!

Comment: Too bad though about the "move my answer up" badge.

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that gets your answer up the page is (1) it has more votes than the answers below it (tied answers are sorted at random), or (2) it's accepted and you didn't ask the question as well.

Editing has no influence on answer position.

Comment: No influence - unless you're sorting by "active", in which case it definitely does.